# How to evaluate this integral when $\lambda < \frac{3}{4}$

Tags: integration

$$\frac{2^{2 \lambda -1} \lambda ^2}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-\lambda \right)^2}\times\int_0^\infty  \left(\frac{q}{z}\right)^{2-2 \lambda } K_{\lambda
   -\frac{3}{2}}(q z) \left[\left((1-4 \lambda ) q^2 z^2-3 (\lambda -1) \lambda  (2 \lambda
   -1)\right) K_{\lambda -\frac{1}{2}}(q z)+q z \left(3 (\lambda -1) \lambda +q^2 z^2\right)
   K_{\lambda +\frac{1}{2}}(q z)\right] dz$$

If we use mathematica, we can obtain
$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\pi  2^{2 \lambda -6} \lambda ^2 (2 (5-2 \lambda )
   \lambda -9) \Gamma (\lambda +1) \Gamma \left(2 \lambda -\frac{3}{2}\right) q^{3-4 \lambda
   }}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-\lambda \right)^2 \Gamma \left(\lambda
   +\frac{3}{2}\right)},\Re(\lambda )>\frac{3}{4}\land q>0\right]$

There is a condition that $\lambda$ should be larger than $\frac{3}{4}$. 
How to evaluate this integral when $\lambda$ is smaller than $\frac{3}{4}$?
Can we just use the analytical continuation of the Gamma functions? This kind of integral is quite frequently appears in AdS/CFT kinds of computations. How people usually deal with it?

Comment: to  get started i would have  a look into here:
http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43#iv

Comment: by the way $K$ are supposed to be Bessel functions?!

Comment: @tired Yes, K is the Bessel K function.